# Concurrent Communicating Kernels in CUDA?

Tags: random, cuda

Lets say I have a device with 2880 cuda cores.

I want to run a Monte Carlo simulation where:

- 2000 threads are each running a sample
- 880 threads are generating random numbers

This is because:

- I only want 2000 samples therefore the other 880 would be sitting idle
- I know that generating random numbers can be slow

Therefore I want to make a pool of random numbers that is replenished continuously by the 880 threads which the 2000 sample threads can take when required.

Is this possible? If so, please provide an example.

Comment: Before trying to do something like this (which in the stated form is not possible in CUDA), you should benchmark a simple version using cuRAND to see if it is **too** slow for your purposes. Premature optimisation is trap that should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: So what Is your question?

Comment: "Please write a code that does this for me."  I'm not sure that is what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Thinking about CUDA cores the same way you think about CPU cores (i.e. wanting to run one thread per core) is not the way to write fast CUDA codes.

Comment: What a nice cozy overengineering

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking what you propose does not even seem to be possible in CUDA and, as others point out, it's surely not a good idea. You may want to pick up a book or an online course first to familiarize with the GPU programming concepts.

More to the point, if you want to dive in straight, [here's an MC pi example](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/tutorials/cuda-monte-carlo-pi/) solved with CUDA, OpenACC and Thrust.